# Removing vertices with modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I would like to know if there is a modifier setup that can delete specific vertex groups.

The decimate modifier's lowest setting seems to leave 3 verts and only has an effect of dissolving/merging by distance, instead I want to be able to delete every vert in a vertex group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the mask modifier: choose your vertex group and press the inverse button [image]

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been using blender for 4 years and have always overlooked this!

Comment: @ZakNelson you are welcome